# How to update ng-model with data from outer source?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

Have the following question.

Consider we have the following HTML code:

```
<div id="container" ng-controller="Controller">
    <my-tag ng-model="values"></my-tag>
</div>
```

And the following controller:

```
var Controller = myApp.controller("Controller", function ($scope, $http, $filter, $q) {

    $scope.values = [];

    $http.get(someURLHere).then(function(response) {
        var data = JSON.parse(response.data);
        $scope.values = data;
    });

        /* And so on ... */

});
```

And here is the directive declaration:

```
myTag.directive('myTag', function() {
    return {
        require: "^ngModel",
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            ngModel : "=",
        },
        controller: ['$scope', '$filter', myTagController],
        templateUrl: /* Here is a path to my template*/,        
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {

            scope.data = scope.ngModel;         

        }
    }
});
```

The tag "my-tag" is my custom directive. It gets some data via ng-model and renders them.
And the `ng-controller="Controller"` is some function which retrieves some data using AJAX and it suppose to write them into the `$scope.values`. After that I expect that they will be sent to `my-tag` via `ng-model="values"`. Next the data suppose to be rendered on the HTML page. But they don't!
I do believe that my data have been retrieved correctly in `Controller`, but there is a problem with updating ng-model in `my-tag`.
What is the best way to "send" data that have been retrieved in `Controller` to ng-model of my custom directive?

Comment: Please add your directive code as well

Answer (score 1):

Update scope variables only in a $scope.apply().

Example for your code:

```
var Controller = myApp.controller("Controller", function ($scope, $http, $filter, $q) {

            $scope.values = [];

            /*
                Getting values via AJAX - assigned to ajaxvalues
            */  
           //still in callback from ajax:
            $scope.$apply(function() {
              $scope.values = ajaxvalues;
            });
           //... end callback
        });
```

See for details: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope

Comment: But I used console debugging from that controller and something like console.log($scope.value) shows me values I want. But they don't transfer to my-tag.

Comment: There could be two issues here: First the console log is triggered directly by you, so it is always printed out. The DOM update (HTML representation of your state) is triggered when Angular detects a change. Angular does not know about a change if it is an external (f.e. ajax) callback. The second issue could be an isolated scope. Easiest to figure out if you check the apply-approach first.

Comment: ``console.log`` will show the updated data because ``$scope.values`` is actually updated to the new values. Your issue is very likely that AngularJS still does not know that you made changes to your scope because your code runs outside the AngularJS environment. AngularJS does dirty-checking for value changes, but to safe resources only when it believes that changes might have occured (i.e. AngularJS related code like a controller has run). This might go away in the future, though, thanks to ``Object.observe``.

Answer (score 1):

If your change on the data is not reflected in the view this is virtually every time because you do stuff outside of the AngularJS framework. This for example applies to event handlers and it applies to the callback of `XMLHttpRequest`. So I assume that you are using the latter function to get your data. You might want to check the `$http` service of AngularJS which will handle this correctly. In the callback you can then set the scope variable. But because AngularJS has this nice feature called promises, you could even do something like this:

```
$scope.values = $http.get('http://my.url/')
  .then(function(response){return response.data;});
```

This will actually bind the promise (which is to be resolved later) to $scope.values, but as AngularJS knows that this is a promise, it will not try to display it in any way. And when later the data arrives the `.then`function will be called which in this example just returnes the JSON data from the response. AngularJS will automatically handle this in the right way and put that JSON data into `$scope.values` then.

If you absolutely need or want to use something like `XMLHttpRequest` or have other code which is not triggered through AngularJS, you will need to make AngularJS aware that you are doing changes to the scope by wrapping the code into `$scope.$apply()` like this:

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
   $scope.values = response.data;
});
```

But you would probably be better off by using `$http`. some wrapper around it like Restangular or if necessary write your own wrapper. And if you do so try to make use of promises if it makes sense as it will make the code still easier and also reusable. Imagine this:

```
function makeRequest(id) {
  return $http.get('...some URL using id...')
     .then(function(response){return response.data;});
}

$scope.variable1 = makeRequest(1);
$scope.variable2 = makeRequest(5);
$scope.variable3 = makeRequest(7);
```

Clasically you would need complicated callback functions knowing where to put the data. Here your callback function does not need to care at all because AngularJS and its promises do all the magic.

Comment: Good, thanks. But could you write a simple example how to notify inner element (which is my custom tag) from outer element (which is my controller that is doing ajax queries)? I tried, but doesn't work... And the problem is with this notification...

Comment: As sprottenwels asked you before: Please provide the source code of your directive as well.

Comment: Done. I've updated my first post, now the directive declaration is there.

Comment: Bu the way. I'm using $http of angular. I've put it in controller at my first post as well.